# Most Expeditious Way of Adding Consecutive Composite Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, self-learning

In helping my 10-year old son with a homework problem that he was trying to solve by rote, I found myself resorting to arithmetic series. In short, I was calculating the arithmetic series from 12 to 37 and then subtracting the primes. He has not done series yet in school.

My questions is two-part: 
1) Was I really using the fastest, most elegant way to solve it?
2) Is there a way to teach him without using series?

Here was the actual question: "Find the sum of all composite numbers between 12 and 37."

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Right now, I really cannot deduce what the original problem was that you were solving. Could you maybe clarify this in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How i would go about this will be:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
&S&=  12 + 13 +...+ 36 + 37\\
+&S&=  37 + 36 +...+ 13 + 12\\
\hline
&2S&= 49 + 49 +...+ 49 + 49\\
&&= 49\cdot (37-12+1)\\
&&= 49\cdot 26
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
S&= 49 \cdot 13\\
&= (50-1)\cdot13\\
 &= 650 -13\\
& = 637\\
\end{align}
$$
Now, the primes between 12 and 37 are $13, 17, 23, 27,29,31, 37$ that have a sum of 177.

Thus, required $\text{sum}= 637-177= 460$.

A slight alteration could be to exclude 37 from the sum from the start itself. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yours may actually be the only way, but you are covertly teaching the kid arithmetic series...

Comment: @AntoniParellada I don't think this would be a bad thing if it was the case. It's not important to understand series to understand the solution, the important thing is that all numbers can be grouped into pairs that each sum up to the same number, which allows the use of multiplication. After all, that's what Gauß did at the age of 9.

Comment: +1 for finding out how to spell Gauss the right way ;-)